# Magento 2 Admin slow when changing into multistore

Tags: magento2

We have a site that is running Magento ver. 2.1.0. They have a number of mutli-sites set up, when you select one of the stores then select a product from one of the stores it takes a long time to load. Is there a way I can speed this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure cache is on.
2. Remove all unwanted customer group.
3. Make sure that no custom module is resulting in some heavy queries.

Steps : Log sql queries and PHP stack and analyse heavy queries and related stack for the code.
Disable modules in question and recheck.